# What is the likeliness other planets could develop saurian life?

Tags: aliens, dinosaurs

I’ve seen a few sci-fi concepts about humans traveling to another planet and discovering dinosaurs as the dominant species. They often look quite unique but share unique features to the Earth equivalent.

But I’m curious, could a planet like this exist? I know another planet with T-rex, Deinonychus, and Brachiosaurus would be close to impossible but what about a planet that has theropods, sauropods, etc?

Comment: It all depends what you mean by theropods and sauropods. As currently understood, theropods are a dinosaurian clade (or a Linnean suborder), and thus could not exist on other worlds, unless somehow space-faring aliens came and took a population of [*Herrerasaurus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herrerasaurus) as pets. But you probably don't mean Theropoda the clade or the suborder, but something else, maybe a general structural plan?

Comment: @AlexP yes, something that is similar in structure plan is also what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Highly unlikely.

To have the same species you would need to have the exact same chain of events which made them arise. Meaning the same starting point, the same point mutation and the same events which selected them over few billion of years. As long as statistics goes, that's impossible.

What you might get is that, through convergent evolution, same functions will be obtained with similar architectures. I.e. the mosasaurus and the dolphin are not the same species, yet they have a similar, hydrodynamic body shape because they are both adapted to hunt in water.